# How to capture 'body' and inside 'body' events in a page[Jquery]

Tags: javascript, jquery-selectors, jquery

what my current Code do :
i have this HTML

```
 <li>
   <span>Logged in as</span>&nbsp;
   <a class="user" href="#"><?php echo $this->loggedas ?></a>&nbsp;
   <a id="loginarrow" href="javascript: void(0);"></a>
 </li>
```

this is my JS for above loginarrow id

```
 $("#loginarrow").click(function() {
   $("#logindrop").toggle("slow");
   return false;
 });
```

its working great but i can close it by clicking it again.
i dont want so i want that  if its open and i click on background so it must close.
for that i did so

```
 $("#loginarrow,body").click(function() {
   $("#logindrop").toggle("slow");
   return false;
 });
```

now its working cool,But Got another problem.

1 = i have many other html elements in Page (Body) in which there are other events to call.so in this case whenever i click other elements in my page so its Toggling my this div loginarrow.

i want the same functionality but not on my other elements only on background.
Any Hint

Comment: please format your code so we don't have to scroll it to read it.

Comment: ok actually in my production pages i am doing so thats y.i am doing it

Comment: @Alnitak its formatted now by Zuul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

close it only when it visible.

```
$("body").click(function() { 
   if ($("#logindrop").is(":visible"))
      $("#logindrop").hide("slow");       
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A fundamental design principle for good browser performance is to only capture events while you're interested in them.

So put your `.click()` handler on the `#loginarrow` element, but in that handler register a *one-off* event handler on the `body` that will close it again.  Something like (untested):

```
$('#loginarrow').click(function() {
    $('#logindrop').show('slow');
    $('body').one('click', function() {
        $('#logindrop').hide('slow');
    });
    return false;
});
```

This will ensure that you're not unnecessarily intercepting *every* click on the `body` except when you really need to.

​See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/vPHaj/

Comment: sir i think it will open it and will hide it than.